# HDMI port not detected on Ubuntu 18.04 (with bumblebee installed)

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

After going through all related questions (dozens of them), I still couldn't figure out.

**system & hardware spec**:

Lenovo Thinkpad P51, NVIDIA Quadro M2200 and Integrated Intel Graphic (hybrid graphic card),

Ubuntu 18.04 (dual boot with Win10)

**symptom**: When connected external monitor with HDMI port, no monitor detected.

- `xrandr` outputs:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88
```

- `lspci |grep HDMI` outputs nothing, `lspci |grep VGA` gives the following:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
```

- `prime-select query` gives `intel` (used to be `nvidia`, but when installing `bumblebee` and avoid the infamous login loop, I switched to Intel.
- Nvidia Driver: `nvidia-driver-410` with packages like `nvidia-410` installed.

**additional note**: This **worked before and still work on Win10** (dual boot), thus shouldn't be a hardware problem, but rather a config or hardware config one in the Ubuntu 18.04 system.

Thanks!

Comment: Same laptop here with the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: @rzan unfortunately, I don't know the solution yet.